# Image won't fill the size of the DIV

Tags: html, css, resize, fill

I'm trying to make the image fill the size of my div (300x300px) but it sits in the corner of it. Any help would be great. Thank you

Here is my HTML

```
<script id="arty-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <section class="myboard">
      {{#each items}}
      <a href={{external_urls.spotify}} target="_blank">
        <div class="boardimage" style="background: url({{images.2.url}}) no-repeat 100% 100%; ;"  title="{{name}}"></div>
      </a>{{/each}}
    </section>
  </script>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.boardimage {
    
    
 position: relative;
  margin: 39px auto;
  width: 300px; height: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
  float: left;
 
}
```

[This is what's happening here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpfNx.png)

[This is without no-repeat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPj5F.png)

I've tried adding height and width to the HTML but it just makes the image disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your text and removed the handlebar code, and used an image from unspash.com. It seems to be working fine, although the code can be improved a lot.

Maybe there's an issue with the image itself. Check if the image renders correctly.

```css
.boardimage {
    
    
 position: relative;
  margin: 39px auto;
  width: 300px; height: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
  float: left;
 
}
```

```html
<a href="" target="_blank">
        <div class="boardimage" style="background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1626246914215-4046df064c1f?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60) no-repeat 100% 100%; ;"  title=""></div>
      </a>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying it out! Is it because my image is starting out at 140x140? Yours is starting out quite big? I need to somehow size it up to 300x300 but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: The image I used is indeed big, but your css width and height is 300 by 300px, so the image must be at least that big.

Comment: I've added an image in the first post without the no-repeat. That's what size the image seems to be? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this and seems working:

```
  .boardimage {
        
   width: 200px; 
      border-radius: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
      float: left;
     
    }
```

Comment: No, when I remove the top attributes like height it just disappears completely!